# How to change spacing between main page and sidebar?

Tags: overleaf, sidebar, altacv

I would like to know how to change spacing between main page and sidebar [AltaCv template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/altacv-template/trgqjpwnmtgv).

I tried this as indicated in overleaf page changing marginparsep parameter:

```
\RequirePackage[margin=2cm,marginparsep=8]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the right usage for change for `marginparsep` parameter.

```
\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=7cm,marginparsep=.5cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm,footskip=2\baselineskip}
```